# PyQt4: How to read a .doc file with all formatting settings using python

Tags: python, format, pyqt4, doc

I want to write all the text In QTextEdit with formatting done like Bold,Font size,font color in a .doc file and then read it again in same format as saved.I Don't know how this can be achieved.Please tell how to read a file that have .doc format.I am Currently using this code to read.

```
def loadFile(self, fileName):
    file = QtCore.QFile(fileName)
    if not file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Ajgar Writer",
                "Cannot read file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
        return False

    instr = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor)
    self.setPlainText(instr.readAll())
    QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

    self.setCurrentFile(fileName)

    self.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.documentWasModified)

    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read or write .doc files using Qt (it is a proprietary Microsoft Office document format). The only options you have are text/html (read and write) or pdf/odf (write only). So if you want to preserve formatting whilst reading and writing, html is really the only viable option.

To read html into a `QTextEdit`, simply do:

```
    # self.setPlainText(instr.readAll())
    self.setHtml(instr.readAll())
```

and to write html, you can do:

```
    outstr << self.toHtml()
```

or use a [QTextDocumentWriter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocumentwriter.html):

```
    writer = QtGui.QTextDocumentWriter(path, 'HTML')
    if not writer.write(self.document()):
        print('ERROR:', writer.device().errorString())
```